# Definir data atual em PHP e colocar no value HTML em um input type='date'

Tags: php, html, formulário

Tentei da seguinte forma mas não funciona

```html
 <form action="add.php" method="POST" name="form1">
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Nome do funcionario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Nome" type="text" name="name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Horario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Hora" type="text" name="hora" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Data</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>" type="date"  name="data" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-green w3-margin-bottom">Adicionar <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </form>
```

ele ignora a parte value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" name="form1">
    <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Nome do funcionario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Nome" type="text" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Horario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Hora" type="text" name="hora" required>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Data</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" type="date"  name="data" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-green w3-margin-bottom">Adicionar <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</form>
```

Substituindo `date('d/m/Y')` por `date('Y-m-d')`, pois esse é o formato adequado para o `input type='date'`

OBS: se modificar o que indiquei no snippet não funcionará pois aqui no stack não há snippet de php

Comment: Muito obrigado, so que quando ele envia pro banco envia 2018-04-12 sabe como posso resolver isso ?

Comment: Você pode fazer a conversão usando `strtotime` e `date` da seguinte forma:

$data_errada = "2018-04-12";
$data_correta = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_errada));

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito e funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 0):

O Formato do atribute value do campo tipo `date` deve estar no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` ou o formato do php (`date('Y-m-d')`), o formato exibido dependerá da configuração de localização do browser. Lembrando que nem todos os browser dão suporte a este tipo de campo.

```html
 <form action="add.php" method="POST" name="form1">
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Nome do funcionario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Nome" type="text" name="name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Horario</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Hora" type="text" name="hora" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Data</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" type="date"  name="data" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-green w3-margin-bottom">Adicionar <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, so que quando ele envia pro banco envia 2018-04-12 sabe como posso resolver isso ?